# Closure of algebra under countable unions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be some set. We define a system of sets $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ by $$\mathcal{C} = \{ S \subseteq X : \text{for all } E \subseteq X \text{ we have } \mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap S) + \mu^*(E \cap S^c),$$ where $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(X) \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}_{+} $ is an outer measure, i.e.

1. $\mu^*(\emptyset) = 0$,
2. For all $A \subseteq B \subseteq X$, $\mu^*(A) \leq \mu^*(B)$,
3. For any sequence $A_i \subseteq X, i =1,2,\ldots$ we have $$\mu^*\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu^* (A_i).$$

It is easy to show that for arbitrary $E,S \subseteq X$ we have $\mu^*(E) \leq \mu^*(E \cap S) + \mu^*(E \cap S^c)$ so that $\mathcal{C} = \{ S \subseteq X : \text{for all } E \subseteq X \text{ we have } \mu^*(E) \geq \mu^*(E \cap S) + \mu^*(E \cap S^c)$.

Also, $\mathcal{C}$ is an algebra.

Now: Show that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under countable unions. I.e., for $A= \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ where $A_i, i=1,2,\ldots$ is a sequence of sets in $\mathcal{C}$, it holds for all $E \subseteq X$ that $$\mu^*(E) \geq \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c).$$

**My try:**

Let $B_j = \cup_{i=1}^j A_i$, $C_1=B_1$ and $C_k = B_k \setminus B_{k-1}, k=2,3,\ldots$. We must have that $B_j \subset \mathcal{C}$ since $B_j$ is a finite union of sets already in $\mathcal{C}$. Further, we know that if $A,B \in \mathcal{C}$ then $A \setminus B \in \mathcal{C}$ by the properties of an algebra. So the $C_k$'s are also in $\mathcal{C}$. Therefore, $$\mu^*(E) \geq \mu^*(E \cap \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^n C_k \right) ) + \mu^*(E \cap \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^n C_k \right)^c ).$$ Also, since $$\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} C_k \right)^c \subset \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^n C_k \right)^c,$$ we have $$\mu^*(E) \geq \mu^*(E \cap \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^n C_k \right) ) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c ).$$ We see that $\cup_{k=1}^n C_k = \cup_{k=1}^n B_k = \cup_{i=1}^n A_i$, so that $$\mu^*(E) \geq \mu^*(E \cap \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right) ) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c ).$$ Can I let $n \to \infty$ here to reach the conclusion?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your question at the end is equivalent to whether $\mu^*(E\cap\left(\bigcup_{i\geq 1} A_i\right)) = \sup_n \mu^*(E\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right))$. I don't why that's the case, a priori.